# Testing contrast between low/high and high/low

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, contrasts

I'm trying to understand the results published in [Sagristano, Trope, and Liberman (2002)](http://psych.nyu.edu/tropelab/publications/SagristanoTrope2002.pdf). Specifically, I don't understand what analysis produced the result highlighted in the screenshot below. The basic design is a 2 (time: near vs distant, between subjects) X 5 (probability of winning: .1, .3 ... .9, within subjects) X 4 (payoff: $4, $6, $8, $10, within subjects) ANOVA. They claim to have tested the hypothesis that

> participants preferred high-probability, low-payoff gambles

A colleague is trying to replicate this study, and we have not been able to figure out what they actually did here. Participants preferred high probability/low payoff to what? Perhaps the (unstated) second half of the hypothesis was "to low probability, high-payoff gambles", but if so I don't understand how they could have tested that. Perhaps the article is simply not clear, or perhaps I'm missing something obvious...

The full article is linked above, and the relevant bit is reproduced here:
[image]

Comment: The quotation seems directly at odds with the left panel of Figure 1, which shows a distinct *lack* of preference for any low-payoff gambles, almost regardless of probability.  The two panels do indeed show an interaction, though: the test seems clear but its interpretation is doubtful.

Comment: @whuber -- can you elaborate on "the test seems clear", because to me it seems about as opaque as it can be. What is the hypothesis, and what analysis would you conduct to test it?

Comment: As stated, the null hypothesis is that the probability-time "interaction" term is zero. The consistent change in slopes of the four curves between the two panels clearly shows such an interaction.

Comment: @whuber -- OK, but the significance test for the interaction of time and probability is reported in the sentence preceding the one I highlighted. That's not the one I'm asking about: I'm trying to figure out what term from what model gave an F value of 171.38 on (1, 116) degrees of freedom, as reported in the highlighted line. It can't be the probability by time interaction, because that has already been reported on the previous line!